# rails many-to-many relationship with nested form link_to_add does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am trying to build complex form for adding Agendas, and I would like to use `link_to_add helper` to dynamicaly add new users for given agenda in form. using `nested_form` gem and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method. These are my models:

```
class Agenda < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through: :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: User

  attr_accessible :name,
                  :address,
                  :owner,
                  :roles_attributes

end


class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agenda
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  attr_accessible :agenda,
                  :role,
                  :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :agendas, through: :roles
end
```

and my controller:

```
class AgendasController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def new
    @agenda = Agenda.new
    @role = @agenda.roles.build
    @user = @role.build_user
  end
end
```

and my form:

```
<%= nested_form_for @agenda do |f| %>
  ....
  <%= f.fields_for :roles do |role_f| %>
    <%= role_f.fields_for :user do |user_f| %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= user_f.label :email, :class=>"control-label" %>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
          <%= user_f.text_field :email %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= role_f.label :role, :class=>"control-label" %>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <%= role_f.text_field :role %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= role_f.link_to_remove "Remove user" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add new users", :roles %>

<% end %>
```

And everything works fine, except for link_to_add, which does not append `fields_for :user` block. How to make link_to_add helper to render whole `fields_for :roles` block together with `fields_for :user` block?

Answer (score 0):

I'ved added a new patch to make [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969493/nested-form-has-many-through-updating-attribute-on-join-model/19738445#19738445) relvant to the newest version of nested_form. Works for me now using this..