# nested_form with has_many :through and link_to_add_hmt function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, has-many-through

I was having the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969493/nested-form-has-many-through-updating-attribute-on-join-model/19738445) The solution was to use the [link_to_add_hmt](https://gist.github.com/stuartchaney/7274894) function which I've added to my source for *nested_form*, but I'm having some issues.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if anyone's familiar with modified this version of function(only real difference appears to be lines 6 and 36).  I have 3 models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :recipe_ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients,
                                  :reject_if => :all_blank,
                                  :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
...

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :recipe
    belongs_to :ingredient
...

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :recipe_ingredients
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients
...
```

Here's my form partial:

```
<%= bootstrap_nested_form_for @recipe, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...
    <%= f.text_field :name, label: "Recipe Name" %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, label: "Description" %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, label: "Image" %>
    <table id="ingredients">
        <%= f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients, :wrapper => false do |ingredient_form| %>
        <tr class="fields">
        <%= ingredient_form.fields_for :ingredient do |ingredient| %>
            <td><%= ingredient.text_field :name, label: "ingredient" %></td>
        <% end %>
            <td><%= ingredient_form.link_to_remove "Remove" %></td>

        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
    <p><%= f.link_to_add_hmt "Add ingredient", :ingredients, recipe_ingredients, :data => { :target => "#ingredients" } %></p>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_area :directions, label: "Directions" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the **error:**

```
undefined method `build_ingredients' for
#<RecipeIngredient:0x007f69057592a0>
```

To the best of my understanding this is happening in this line in link_to_add_hmt(36 from the above link):

```
model_object.send("build_#{association_two}".to_sym)
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the function wrong, I'm missing something, or if the code in link_to_add_hmt doesn't work for some reason.

Also I'm running Rails 4.2.4 on Ruby 2.1.0, if that is at all related to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `link_to_add_hmt` method in your helper? If you are using that solutions.

Comment: I added the function to nested_form-0.3.2/lib/nested_form/builder_mixin.rb right after `link_to_add`.  Calling `link_to_add_hmt` isn't the issue.  I know it's being called, but when it's calling it's saying `build_ingredients` is undefined which looks to be what `model_object.send("build_#{association_two}".to_sym)` is calling

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, after adding this line to troubleshoot:

```
raise "debug: association => #{association}, association_two => #{association_two}, model_object => #{model_object.methods}"
```

I found that I had a typo.  The *build_other* method generated by a *belongs_to* relationship is singular(in this case *recipe_ingredients.build_ingredient*).  I had typed *:ingredients* (plural).